# Makefile auto-dependency problem

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to set a Makefile which does auto-dependency generation. I red this page http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html and write my own Makefile :

Edit : 
I made some changes following Beta comments.
Now, all files and the makefile are at the same level.
But not more luck.

```
CC = gcc
LD = gcc
RM = rm -rf
MAKEDEPEND = gcc -M $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $*.d $<

CFLAGS = -Wall -g

INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/CUnit
LIB = -llibcunit

SRC = lib_dac.c
SRC += main.c

OBJS = $(SRC:.c=.o)

PROG = tests

all: $(OBJS)

%.o : %.c
    $(MAKEDEPEND); \
        cp $*.d $*.P; \
        sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
        -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $*.d >> $*.P; \
        rm -f $*.d
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ $<

-include $(SRCS:.c=.P)

PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.exe
    $(RM) *.P
```

But I can not get it worked. When I touch lib_dac.h, on which depends lib_dac.c nothing happen.
Am I missing something ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any comments on the syntax are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAKEDEPEND` is giving you the dependencies for `lib_dac.o`, not for `src/lib_dac.o`. When Make tries to build `src/lib_dac.o`, it doesn't know that `lib_doc.h` is involved.

There are several ways to fix this, but the choice depends on how you want to handle the object files (e.g. `lib_dac.o`). I notice that you define a `BIN_PATH`, but don't use it; instead you build the objects in `src`. Is that your intention?

**EDIT:**
Here is a quick fix to put the object files in `bin/`. (Make is good at using files *there* to build files *here*, but not the other way around.)

```
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,bin/%.o,$(SRC))

bin/%.o : %.c
  ...

vpath %.c src
```

Comment: Thanks, I change my makefile and moved it in the souce directory. What I don't understand is when does the makefile look for the dependencies ? I can see when it creates them but not when it uses them.

Comment: @Nicolas: With `-include $(SRCS:.c=.P)`, the dependencies are incorporated into the makefile.

Comment: Yes I know. So for each file there are two rules. The one with %o: %c and the one created with MAKEDEPEND. Am I right ?

Comment: @Nicolas: loosely speaking, yes, there are two rules for each object file. The one created by MAKEDEPEND has prerequisites but no commands, so those prerequisites are simply added to the prerequisites of the pattern rule (`%.o: %.c`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find a typo in my makefile. In the include I wrote `$SRCS` instead of `$SRC`. Damned copy/paste.

It works well now, but currently all files are in the same directory and I don't really like that.

But the dependency generation works, so problem solved.

Comment: Where do you want the files? Maybe we can help.

Comment: Well, I like to have the sources in a folder src and binaries in a bin folder. And usually I put the makefile above those two directories.